Arabian Nights type movie, comic sidekick turns out to be a ghost
I saw this film many years ago, and it was old then.  Probably 40s or 50s, maybe 60s at the latest. It was live action and in colour.
It is an Arabian Nights/ Sinbad/ Thief of Baghdad type story. The young hero gains a comic relief sidekick who helps him.
At the end of the film, the hero sees a statue of his sidekick.  It is someone who died years previously.
As the hero kisses the heroine, the final shot of the film is the statue, which is now smiling.

Roughly how old did the sidekick appear to be?

Middle aged. Maybe about 50.  IIRC, it was a long time ago,

Identified by someone on another forum.
Thief of Baghdad, 1961.




Karim rescues Amina and returns her to her father. The Blue Rose is destroyed, but Karim plucks a white rose and gives it to Amina, telling her that if she truly loves him, then it is blue. She takes the rose and tells him that it is blue, and it immediately turns blue, curing her. The sultan welcomes Karim as his son-in-law and successor. Karim sees a bust of the mysterious old man, but the sultan tells him that it is a bust of his late uncle, the great Sultan Achim I.

